# How to deploy a backend with no database

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, backend

I'm pretty new to programming and am developing a small webpage for my company. Essentially there's a form on the frontend where users will fill in information, then I've written a .NET app that acts as an HTTP server to listen for the requests and store the information in a plain text file (I know this is bad practice, but there is zero sensitive information being sent or stored.)

I have it all working so that if I run the backend and webpage locally I can do exactly what I want, but I'm kind of stuck on what I do moving forward. I have a webhost that I have the domain hosted at, but I don't have any idea on what to do with the backend application.? Ideally I'd just want to set the server running as I would on my own machine, but I don't know how this all works in practice.

Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the code with no database, you can use SQLite which is more effective and secure than just a file for storage.

You need to set up a service to run a deployed code in a server which consists of an executable file path and other necessary things for the server.

[Dotnet Deployment Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)